# Error when setting UserInfo in UILocalNotification

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification, userinfo

I'm trying to attach an NSManagedObjectID to a UILocalNotification but keep getting the error:
Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')

Here's my code (taskID is an NSManagedObjectID):

```
// Create the new notification
UILocalNotification *newNotice = [[notificationClass alloc] init];
[newNotice setFireDate:date];
[newNotice setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[newNotice setAlertBody:@"Test text"];

// Add the object ID to the userinfo
NSDictionary *myUserInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:taskID forKey:@"TaskID"];
newNotice.userInfo = myUserInfo;
```

taskID is passed into the function with this code (first parameter):

```
addNotification([task objectID], [task taskname], [task taskexpiry]);
```

task is an NSManagedObject and that code has been tested and working fine for a long time.

From everything I've read this should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Post the code where `taskID` is defined and instantiated, chances are that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Added a bit more info in the post on where taskID is coming from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `userInfo` must be a valid property list.  See [*What is a Property List?*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2).  `NSManagedObjectID` is not any of the types allowed in a property list.

Try using `[[taskID URIRepresentation] absoluteString]` as your `userInfo`.  You'll have to use `-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:]` later to turn it back into an `NSManagedObjectID`.